# Uso de de "mi negra" como apelativo cariñoso

Tags: etimología, expresiones

El otro día oía a alguien referirse a su acompañante (una chica de pelo negro) como "mi negra". Era evidente que era un apelativo cariñoso.

La primera vez que oí el término usado de esa manera fue en la cumbia "[Como mi negra](https://youtu.be/trQy3IUk-Ek?t=884)" que era parte de la [Cantata del Adelantado Don Rodrigo Díaz de Carreras](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trQy3IUk-Ek), de Les Luthiers. En esta obra dice el personaje de Carlos Núñez:

> [...] Fui de pronto conmovido por los **ojos *renegridos*** de una **morena**...

Y a esta morena de ojos negros se le dedica la cumbia en cuestión.

Me dio por buscar el término en el DLE, y vi que [negro/a](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QN0nGts#KSaoNfh) puede ser:

> 16. m. y f. *And. y Am.* [Usado] como voz de cariño entre casados, novios o personas que se quieren bien.

Lo que sí me sorprendió es que el término se use también en Andalucía y no sólo en América, porque en España no llegué nunca a oírlo en boca de los andaluces que conozco.

¿Cuál el origen de este término como apelativo cariñoso? ¿A quién se le puede aplicar este apelativo?

Aunque pueda parecer obvio, yo en su momento pensé que era para personas de raza negra y no le di más importancia, pero repasando: el ejemplo de Les Luthiers (donde solo dicen "ojos y cabello negro", sin implicar más); que el otro día lo vi usar para agasajar a una chica de pelo negro pero piel blanca; y que se usa en Andalucía, donde no abundan las poblaciones de etnia negra más que en otros sitios de España, me hace preguntarme si se refiere a piel negra u otros atributos (pelo negro, ojos negros).
Aparte, ¿es distinto su uso en Andalucía que en América?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El uso de *negro/a* como apelativo para personas en Latinoamérica está lleno de vericuetos y trampas. Yo sólo puedo hablar por mi experiencia en Argentina. *Negro* y *negra* pueden ser usados como apelativos y vocativos; con el posesivo *mi* adquiere un tono cariñoso, íntimo. *Mi negra* puede ser una novia o esposa y también una hija; no sé si alguna vez escuché *mi negro* en boca de una mujer para referirse a su marido, pero si lo escuchase no me extrañaría. *Mi negrito/a* para referirse a un/a hijo/a también es común (cf. la canción *[Duerme negrito](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duerme_negrito)*).

Al igual que en Andalucía, en Argentina hay muy pocas personas de piel negra (afrodescendientes, e incluyendo inmigrantes de países con gran población afrodescendiente, como el vecino Brasil), de manera que *negro* no es un término racial en este uso, si bien se asocia a personas de tez medianamente morena (para nuestro promedio). Yo lo he oído aplicado a personas con gran variedad de facciones, aunque no, quizá lógicamente, a personas de tez muy clara o de cabello rubio.

Yo tengo tez morena y me han llamado *negro* (vocativo, no sobrenombre) infinidad de veces, pero me he cruzado con personas para quienes *negro* era un vocativo genérico sin importar a quién se dirigían. Mi madre probablemente me ha dicho *mi negrito* muchas veces; mi esposa, que se tuesta fácilmente al sol pero no es especialmente morena, es *la Negra* para sus amigos de años.

En el [portugués brasileño](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/nego) *nego, nega, neguinho, neguinha*, alteraciones de *negro*, etc., son términos de afecto similares a los que se describen en el DLE, y al igual que aquí, tampoco se limitan a personas de piel negra o afrodescendientes. A diferencia de allí, donde *nego* también puede significar "persona cualquiera, tipo, sujeto", en Argentina hay que tener cierto cuidado con esto porque *negro* también se usa peyorativamente para referirse a personas de un estrato socioeconómico particular (sobre esto no quiero inundar con detalles la respuesta). El contexto es clave; llamar a un compañero *mi negro* nunca va a malentenderse.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo y complemento diciendo que es exactamente igual aquí en Colombia donde si tenemos un buen porcentaje de población afro-descendiente.

Comment: También de acuerdo con la respuesta; en Colombia efectivamente usamos cariñosamente los téminos negro/negra, negrito/negrita y  no necesariamente para referirse o llamar así a personas que sean afrodescendientes o de piel morena u oscura. Y que recuerde no se usa de ninguna manera para indicar discriminación racial o étnica.

Answer (score 2):

En Puerto Rico se usa el término como sinónimo de "mi amor", "mi cariño" o entre amigos como saludo cariñoso "¡..qué haces, negro!". El término se usa aunque seas blanco de los que ni siquiera cogen un tan bajo el sol.

Nadie piensa por qué con el uso el término se convirtió en muestra de cariño; y a nadie le importa ni piensa sobre esto. Espero que la estupidez que sucede en EE.UU. sobre el uso de palabras nunca llegue a Latinoamérica.